# Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH, when I run cqlsh command

Tags: linux, python-2.7, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

server detail: Linux version 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC) )

cassandra version: 3.6.0

Python 2.7.6

I use this document for helping (http://imti.co/post/152084743878/cassandra-install-cassandra-39-on-centos-6x)

I follow all the steps of above helping doc, In the last step of "cqlsh"

when I run command cqlsh getting error.

> Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH.
>
> You might try "pip install cassandra-driver".
>
> Python: /usr/local/bin/python
>
> Error: can't decompress data;  zlib not available

I installed python driver and zlib also but still getting same error.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues on CentOS.
Please check the step#4 [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installPython27RHEL.html)

Answer (score 0):

Download [`cqlsh-astra-20201104-bin.tar`](https://downloads.datastax.com/#cqlsh)

Extract `cqlsh-astra-20201104-bin.tar`

Go to `\cqlsh-astra-20201104-bin\cqlsh-astra\zipfiles`

Extract `six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any` and `cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.24.0`

Copy `six.py` file and `\cassandra` folder to `\cqlsh-astra-20201104-bin\cqlsh-astra\bin`

Run `python cqlsh.py --version`